# Any way to save/manage finder states? Not just the windows, but their location and layout too?

Tags: finder, window-manager

I'd like to be able to hit a hotkey and load a saved state of the finder. Not just the window locations and size, but also their location, layout, (history?).

There seem to be many solutions for saving window size/location, but nothing specific to the Finder windows themselves.

Is there an app or script that can do this?

If not, where do I begin to try to script something myself?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this would do **everything**, but if you could get something to put in a file the path to every open Finder window, and then put that file and the .DS_Store from each of those paths into a tarball, I think you would have most of it.

To restore, **first** put each .DS_Store back, **then** open all the directory names stored.